# Word 2007-2013 Content control

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-xe

I have a word document contains some content control (Rich text, check boxes).
Normally I can call content control:

```
ActiveDocument.ContentControls.item(1).Range.Text = "something"
ActiveDocument.ContentControls.item(1).Checked = True
```

But some of the control inside shapes (text box) and they can not be called this way.

How can I use these controls?

Answer (score 1):

Word has a number of different "StoryRanges" (the main body text "Story", various Header/Footer Stories, and so on. In this case the Controls are not in the Main Body story and you need to specify where they are. e.g. in the case you mention I think you will find them in

```
ActiveDcouemnt.StoryRanges(wdTextFrameStory).ContentControls
```

but if, for example, the textboxes are in a Header you may need to use a different StoryRange.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the answer was not that simple. But I managed to solve the problem. The shapes was grouped, that was the main problem. I had to ungroup them and after that

ActiveDocument.Shapes.Item(1).Select

Selection.Range.ContentControls.Item(1).Checked := True

Thank for the help anyway.